# persistant message queues

Tags: message-queue

I have several services on different machines and a message-passing system suits my problem.

Reliability - sent messages always delivered, even if one end goes down - is the key concern, although it should also be fast and reasonably bandwidth-efficient.

So which message queue should I use?

Comment: What language / framework do you use for development?

Comment: A real mix, so portable with lots of bindings is best; certainly python and java on both windows and linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) is a solution that covers all your requirements.  It also has bindings for many languages (Java, C, Python, ...).

RabbitMQ servers are also available for both *nix and Windows environments.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using Windows OS, you can use MSMQ (Microsoft Message queue). It allows durable and transactional message delivery. If you use .NET you can use NServiceBus, which operates on top of MSMQ.